# how to do automatic tests after a package build in R, Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, testthat

how to do automatic tests after package build in R - Rstudio - testthat

i have tried:

```
testPath=paste(getwd(),"/tests/R/",sep="")
codePath=paste(getwd(),"/R/",sep="")
auto_test(test_path=testPath, code_path=codePath)
```

but this react each time i change a file, not each time i rebuild my package... 
it works for now... but if my package becomes bigger that will just take to much time... 
also i like to have my console available during coding... (don't like the idea of a 2nd console)

Comment: I'll post as a comment for now and if it's what you want I'll clean up as an answer.  Basically you need to make a directory in the main repo called `tests`.  In there you a file called `testthat.R` (I don't think the name has to be that but I copied Hadley's repo) and another directory called `testthat` with all the unit test .R files.    So the best way is to go steal from the master: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis  See the `tests` directory?  This approach does the unit testing during the build.

Comment: i did that... it does not do the checking after the build... it does do the checking if you type: "check()" or press: ctrl+shift+t ... which is getting close

Comment: It does it during the build as part of the checks.  See the travis-ci output here:https://travis-ci.org/trinker/qdap  I's the line that says: `* checking tests ...
  Running ‘testthat.R’ [21s/22s]`

Comment: this is all i get...
`* installing *source* package ‘readODS’ ...`
`** R`
`** preparing package for lazy loading`
`** help`
`*** installing help indices`
`** building package indices`
`** testing if installed package can be loaded`
`* DONE (readODS)`

and it does not run the test... cause i made sure it would fail!... you know to test the testing :)

Comment: Do you have the repo in a place it can be forked?  Do you have build as `--as-cran`?

Comment: https://github.com/phonixor/readODS  - already on CRAN btw and yes i used --as-cran for the check() thing.